# Async await test cases failed using jest javascript testing library

Tags: javascript, async-await, jestjs

I am using Jest testing Library for some simple async/await functions. But it's failing again and again as I am very new to jest. and can you please answer what `expect.assertions(1)` do here

```
    function fetchData() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve({
        id: 1,
        name: "test",
        age: 20,
      });
    }, 1000);
  });
}

test("test async await", async () => {
  const data = await fetchData();
  expect(data.id).toBe(1);
});

test("async await error", async () => {
  expect.assertions(1);
  try {
    await fetchData();
  } catch (e) {
    expect(e).toMatch("error");
  }
});
```

Comment: At a glance, the second test should always fail because you haven't told setup 'fetchData' to reject.  What is the condition that you are trying to test where `fetchData` actually does *not* resolve?  I think `.assertions(1)` is setting up the test so that when the test is finished, if you have not seen at least one assertion, then fail.  For this kind of test you should probably look into the [`.toThrow` matcher](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tothrowerror)

Comment: mr rogers - can you update the above code

Answer (score 0):

As I pointed out in the comments, the test for the "failure" case doesn't really make sense if this `fetchData` is the *real* function because it never 'rejects'.  To test the failure case in Jest, you'd need to somehow trigger the Promise.reject case.

If we assume this `fetchData` is a wrapper on an api call or something else, we could imagine something like this.

You might have a library or module that is making api calls like:

```js
// api.js
const api = {
  actualFetchData: () => {
    // this is the function that actually connects
    // to a data source and returns data
  },
};

module.exports = api;
```

And your `fetchData` function which you're trying to test looks like:

```js
// fetchData.js
const api = require("./api");

function fetchData() {
  return api.actualFetchData();
}
module.exports = fetchData;
```

Then, assuming this structure matches what you're working on, you can mock the internals of `fetchData` and test both success and failure cases by mocking `actualFetchData` and using `mockResolvedValue` and `mockRejectedValue`.

```js
// fetchData.test.js
const fetchData = require("./fetchData");
const api = require("./api");

jest.mock("./api");

const mockApiFetch = jest.fn();
api.actualFetchData = mockApiFetch;

describe("when the underlying fetch resolves", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    mockApiFetch.mockResolvedValue({
      id: 1,
      name: "test",
      age: 20,
    });
  });

  test("test async await", async () => {
    const data = await fetchData();
    expect(data.id).toBe(1);
  });
});

describe("when the underlying fetch fails", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    mockApiFetch.mockRejectedValue(new Error("failed to get data"));
  });

  test("async await error", async () => {
    expect(() => fetchData()).rejects.toThrow("failed to get data");
  });
});
```

You'll notice I didn't use the `expect.assertions` because it didn't seem like it added anything to the test.  Instead, just used `toThrow` with text that matches the error.

I realize this is making some assumptions about a system that you haven't fully described in the initial question so this may not be exactly what you're trying to get at.  Hopefully it's close.